Mutate to concatenate columns that contain a specific string in their names
I'm trying to create a new column that concatenates all values of a specific set of columns that contain a specific string in their names, with a semi-colon separator. I'm working within dplyr, so I'm seeking a tidyverse solution.
I attempted to use grepl() in combination with mutate(), case_when(), and paste() to identify the columns that contained the string I wanted in their names ("Games") and concatenate their contents together into a new column. When that failed, I attempted to use str_detect instead, but that didn't work out.
As far as I can tell, my issue is that I can't correctly instruct the code to evaluate all column names and then return the ones that have a string that contains my specified pattern. I've tried using contains("Games"), colnames(.x), and other variations on those arguments. I know I could do this if I specifically named every column I wished to paste together, but I prefer a relative solution that prevents me from typing out multiple names.
Thank you!
# Sample Data

test<-as_tibble(data.frame(`ID` = c("1","2","3"),
                           `Gender` = c("Female","Male","Non-Binary"),
                           `Games_Chess`=c("Chess",NA,"Chess"),
                           `Games_Clue`=c("Clue",NA,NA),
                           `Games_Scrabble`=c("Scrabble",NA,"Scrabble")))
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  ID    Gender     Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>         
1 1     Female     Chess       Clue       Scrabble      
2 2     Male       NA          NA         NA            
3 3     Non-Binary Chess       NA         Scrabble  

# Desired Output

ID    Gender     Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble Games    
1     Female     Chess       Clue       Scrabble       Chess; Clue; Scrabble
2     Male       NA          NA         NA             NA
3     Non-Binary Chess       NA         Scrabble       Chess; Scrabble  

# Attempted Code 1

test<-test%>%
  mutate(`Games` = case_when(str_detect(colnames(test),"Games") ~ paste(.x, collapse = ";"), TRUE ~ NA))

# Error Code 1

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Games = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the right-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error:
! object '.x' not found

# Attempted Code 2
test<-test%>%
  mutate(`Games` = case_when(grepl("Games",.) ~ paste(., collapse = ";"), TRUE ~ NA))

# Error Code 2

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Games = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error:
! `Games` must be size 3 or 1, not 4.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


Though not entirely dplyr-based, the following solution does still fall under the tidyverse using tidyr:
test %>%
  tidyr::unite(
    # Name of new column
    col = "Games",
    # Select columns to unite using tidy-select syntax
    dplyr::starts_with("Games"),
    # Specify semi-colon as separator
    sep = "; ",
    # Keep original Games_* columns
    remove = FALSE,
    # Remove NA's prior to concatenation
    na.rm = TRUE
  )

Which results in the following output:
#>   ID     Gender                 Games Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble
#> 1  1     Female Chess; Clue; Scrabble       Chess       Clue       Scrabble
#> 2  2       Male                              <NA>       <NA>           <NA>
#> 3  3 Non-Binary       Chess; Scrabble       Chess       <NA>       Scrabble

Edit: optionally, if you'd like the new column to be at the very end of your data, then you can add the following code at the end using the %>% pipe operator to move the new column to the end:
dplyr::relocate(
    Games,
    .after = dplyr::everything()
  )


Thank you!!!!!!

rowwise() is usually considered slow, but it's perfectly fine to use unless you're dealing with large amounts of data
library(dplyr)

test |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(Games = paste(na.omit(c_across(c(starts_with("Games")))), collapse = "; ")) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(Games = sub("^$", NA, Games))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   ID    Gender     Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble Games                
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>          <chr>                
#> 1 1     Female     Chess       Clue       Scrabble       Chess; Clue; Scrabble
#> 2 2     Male       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>           <NA>                 
#> 3 3     Non-Binary Chess       <NA>       Scrabble       Chess; Scrabble

You can also define a complicated function separately for readability. starts_with() is nice but I'll usually use matches() to use a regex.
paste_func <- function(vec) {
  na.omit(vec) |>
    paste(collapse = "; ") |>
    sub("^$", NA, x = _)
}

test |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(Games = paste_func(c_across(matches("^Games")))) |>
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   ID    Gender     Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble Games                
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>          <chr>                
#> 1 1     Female     Chess       Clue       Scrabble       Chess; Clue; Scrabble
#> 2 2     Male       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>           <NA>                 
#> 3 3     Non-Binary Chess       <NA>       Scrabble       Chess; Scrabble

For larger datasets where rowwise() might get a little slow, you can coerce a portion of the data frame to a matrix with apply() and assign results accordingly. Since apply() takes a matrix you'll want to only supply data of all the same class.
result <- test
cols_to_paste <- colnames(result)[grepl("^Games", colnames(result))]
result$Games <- apply(result[, cols_to_paste], 1, FUN = paste_func)

result

#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   ID    Gender     Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble Games                
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>          <chr>                
#> 1 1     Female     Chess       Clue       Scrabble       Chess; Clue; Scrabble
#> 2 2     Male       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>           <NA>                 
#> 3 3     Non-Binary Chess       <NA>       Scrabble       Chess; Scrabble

I usually find this more trouble than it's worth but you can also pivot_longer() to make column operations easier and then put it back to its original wide format with pivot_wider()
test |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(matches("^Games")) |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(Games = paste(na.omit(value), collapse = "; ")) |>
  ungroup() |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider() |>
  mutate(Games = sub("^$", NA, Games)) |>
  relocate(all_of(colnames(test)))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   ID    Gender     Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble Games                
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>          <chr>                
#> 1 1     Female     Chess       Clue       Scrabble       Chess; Clue; Scrabble
#> 2 2     Male       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>           <NA>                 
#> 3 3     Non-Binary Chess       <NA>       Scrabble       Chess; Scrabble


In base this could be:
test$Games <- apply(test[, 3:5], 1, paste, collapse = '; ')
test$Games <- gsub('NA; ', '', test$Games) # partial cleanup of repeat NA
test$Games[which(test$Games == 'NA')] <- NA # set NA(s) if exist
test
  ID     Gender Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble                 Games
1  1     Female       Chess       Clue       Scrabble Chess; Clue; Scrabble
2  2       Male        <NA>       <NA>           <NA>                  <NA>
3  3 Non-Binary       Chess       <NA>       Scrabble       Chess; Scrabble


Probably you can try this
test$Games <- apply(
  test[startsWith(names(test), "Games")],
  1,
  \(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, toString(na.omit(x)))
)

such that
> test
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  ID    Gender     Games_Chess Games_Clue Games_Scrabble Games
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>          <chr>
1 1     Female     Chess       Clue       Scrabble       Chess, Clue, Scrabble
2 2     Male       NA          NA         NA             NA
3 3     Non-Binary Chess       NA         Scrabble       Chess, Scrabble


Well, certainly more concise than mine and directs me to more base function that are always useful, though seemed useful to keep  as  rather than character NA, (depending on next uses of results and tests that might be applied, is.na& etc. after conversion to char.)
